# Bash- how to select a directory based on the number of files it contains

Tags: linux, bash

I want to select all the sub-directories in a given folder that have a certain number (in this case, 75) files within them. Then I want to take the name of each of these sub-directories and assign it a new variable name to use throughout the rest of my script.

Comment: Do you want to count sub sub directories as well or only files? What about files in sub sub sub directories? What have you got so far? We won't write the script for you but would be happy to help out with a _specific_ problem. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Here an idea.

filecount is the number of files you want to find.
For each folder with this number of files, a variable will be created. The variable-name is the folder-name but the "/" were substituted by "_"

```
filecount=1
for i in `find folder -type d`
do

count=`ls $i|wc -l`
if [ $count -eq $filecount ]
then
export `echo $i | sed -e "s/\//_/g"`=`ls -d $PWD/$i`
fi
done
env | grep folder
```